# What kind of wave is light?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, photons

When people say about wave-like nature of a photon, what do they mean:

1. Pressure-like **wavefront** - it moves as a sphere (or a bulge on a surface) and then if we measure pressure at one single point (after the front moved further) - it will raise and fall "drawing" a wave.
2. Something like an **arrow** - it moves in the space, but it also has internal vibrations. Different points of it have different curvature.
3. Something that just moves along one axis, but also **moves up-and-down** along the other axis.
4. Something else?

Option #1 means the photon itself doesn't "know" anything about waves - the wave is the impact that was left after it. Option #2 and #3 mean that crests/troughs are intrinsic to the photon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly are light waves?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146253/)

Comment: Eh, I wish it were fully answered in that thread :)